# What time zone is used for operating an airplane?

Tags: aircraft-operations, time

This might be a silly question but my thinking was the following:

There has to be a definition of *time* in an airplane for the logging of data and so on, but what definition would that be assuming a flight goes across timezones?

Would it be the local time at the airport of **departure**? Or at that of **arrival**? or maybe even a third, commonly agreed upon time (e.g., GMT)?

---

The idea came from a story of a friend that was traveling with the ship from Italy (GMT+1) to Greece (GMT+2). The cafeteria on board had a sign saying that it opens at 14:00, but on 14:20 local Italy time, while the ship was anchored in Italy, he was denied service by the crew saying that the sign was referring to Greece local time; where the ship "belongs".

Comment: [Related](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/16818/62), maybe a dupe?

Comment: @Pondlife Nice find. My googling did not bring it up; my title is catchier.

Comment: Certainly related. This question asks "what", that one asks "why".  The question of dupe/no dupe could go either way.

Comment: Some years ago I had the actual unfortunate (or fortunate depending on perspective) experience of a flight that had a stopover prior to arrival at my location.  All THREE times were for 2:00 AM local - but the FUN part was it was on the day where daylight savings time changed so no-one knew the actual UTC time because of everything being listed in local times.  They just gave me a 4 hour window as best they could do.

Comment: There's a huge difference between what's used internally in the computers and what's displayed to customers - what are you asking about?

Comment: @pipe Having been a customer myself, I know what is displayed and communicated. I am asking about the pilot-to-plane/ATC interactions, plane internals and so on.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The pilot (and the ATC) use the [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) (Coordinated Universal Time). The flight's departure and arrival are in terms of the local times at the respective airports.

As for data logging, the FDR/CVR usually records in UTC (preferred) or the relative time count (usually count increments each 4 seconds of system operation). See [Appendix M to Part 121 - Airplane Flight Recorder Specifications](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/appendix-M_to_part_121#), for example.

Answer (score 24):

[ICAO SARPs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standards_And_Recommended_Practices) Annex 2 (Rules of the Air) states:

> **3.5 Time**
>
> 3.5.1 Coordinated Universal Time (UTC) shall be used and
>   shall be expressed in hours and minutes and, when required,
>   seconds of the 24-hour day beginning at midnight.
>
> 3.5.2 A time check shall be obtained prior to operating a
>   controlled flight and at such other times during the flight as
>   may be necessary.
>
> *Note.— Such time check is normally obtained from an air
>   traffic services unit unless other arrangements have been made
>   by the operator or by the appropriate ATS authority.*
>
> 3.5.3 Wherever time is utilized in the application of data
>   link communications, it shall be accurate to within 1 second of
>   UTC.

The above should apply to almost every country when it comes to international civil aviation. Militaries and uncontrolled flights are not covered by the above.

Answer (score 5):

The planes use UTC time. The same as ATC.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! A link to UTC would be great too (e.g., [this](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/gmt-utc-time.html))

Answer (score 2):

Let me add that pilots, ATC, and others use UTC, (not GMT) but it's common for customer-facing times to be in the time zone of the event. For example, a Flight from Florida to Alabama may land before it departs on the ticket.

Usually, ticket times are listed in local time. So Departing 1:00 pm Arriving 12:48 pm could actually appear on a ticket.

Comment: Well, GMT *might* mean the same thing as UTC. It is, however, ambiguous.

Comment: @coteyr, Please explain how pilots don't use GMT.  If there is a difference between UTC, GMT, and Zulu I would like to understand it.  Thanks.

Comment: https://www.timeanddate.com/time/gmt-utc-time.html its mostly semantic but UTC is a system of time where GMT is a time zone.

Comment: Zulu, on the other hand, is just shorthand for UTC + 0 Zero hours. For example, a time may be written 20:20z-5:00 (in theory) which is the same at 01:20z