# Which timezone do airspaces that cross a time zone boundary belong to on a VFR sectional?

Tags: aeronautical-charts, time

The Albuquerque VFR sectional claims that the airspace table in the margin use local time, but some of the airspaces in the table cross timezone boundaries. Which  timezone do those airspaces belong to?

BRONCO 3 MOA is an example that crosses the New Mexico-Texas border and therefore from Mountain to Central Time:
[image: BRONCO 3 MOA]

See this excerpt from the margin which states that local times are used and lists the effective times for the Bronco 3 MOA:

[image]

So, in the case of the Bronco 3, are the listed "local" times MST/MDT or CST/CDT?

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE! [This question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/52971/62) might be helpful

Comment: I agree that that question and probably [this](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/16818/why-does-aviation-use-zulu-time-instead-of-the-local-time) one as well are related. I'm hoping that the answer explains how to convert that airspace into UTC time because there are two different ways to do it depending on where in the airspace you are.

Comment: Good question. I don’t think I have ever seen the edge case addressed, but ForeFlight says it is Mountain Time. My guess is that since this is on the Albuquerque sectional chart that’s why Mountain is used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The times listed on the margin of the VFR Sectional chart are generally local time. In fact, the effective times that the FAA lists are also published in local time. However, in the case of a Special Use Airspace (SUA) that covers multiple time zones, the FAA specifies which time zone is used for local time.

The FAA publishes these details of SUA in the [JO 7400.10A](https://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Order/JO_7400.10A_Special_Use_Airspace_(2019).pdf) "Special Use Airspace".

You ask specifically about the Bronco 3 MOA. In the 7400.10A, the following details are currently published for the Bronco 3:

[image]

So, while Fort Worth Center is the controlling agency, the times of use are given in Mountain Time. This makes sense since the using agency is out of Cannon AFB in New Mexico.

---

Compare this to the nearby Lancer MOA (entirely in Central Time) for which the 7400.10A only lists the time as "local time":

[image]

Comment: This is exactly the type of answer I was looking for, thank you!