# Is there a standard time zone for flight schedules?

Tags: flight-schedules, time

I was reading a question on Travel.SE. The asker was asking whether the time on his ticket was in Daylight Savings Time or in standard time. I would imagine flight schedules are supposed to be time-zone/DST agnostic so as to avoid any potential confusion and timezone conversions.

A commenter mentioned UTC time, which makes sense to me.

So my question is: is there a standard time zone or other time standard used for tickets and/or flight schedules?

Comment: @Him Not really a duplicate, but indeed worth pointing the user in that direction to explain why Zulu is used in Aviation.

Comment: Moonman, also reference this: [Does DST affect local airspace?](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/13657/572).

Comment: I call time on my ticket as my flight schedule. Are you asking about flight schedule as seen from passenger or pilot?

Answer (score 10):

Customer facing documents like boarding passes and itineraries typically show local times for ease of use.  Just use airport clocks.  I would not trust the flying public to compute UTC.  It would be chaos.

Crew facing documents will usually be set to UTC, or zulu time.